# How to implement overlay-tableview for search?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Youtube search on iOS

[image]

I guess it's a tableview. 
How do I make occupy variable amount of screen space like the image?

I can start with the terms I need to search, or concepts I need to learn. throw me some hints please.

Comment: you asked the `beyonce` placed position in the list

Answer (score 1):

Just add it as subview and set its height to something like:

```
CGFloat tableViewHeight = searchResultsNr * cellHeight;
```

Also make sure that there is some max height for it, so all cells are visable for more results like:

```
CGFloat maxHeight = screenHeight - serchBarHeight - keyboardHeight;
```

And just change frame on reloading your data, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as a full screen table view that is also added as a subview of the main view but hidden when the search is not active.

For this effect, just use a black translucent background color for your table view, your cells must have the white background color.

Hope that helps.